# Size out of limits in array made with malloc

Tags: beginner, c, array

I'm applying what I learned in statistics class to a program to calculate everything automatically, but encountered an unexpected 'mistake' in my code. I say unexpected, because it's not the first time I use malloc() to make a variable sized array and used reference from my previous work, but it goes off limits with the resulting size, when earlier, it worked fine as intended.

Can you tell me why the size ends up wrong?

I know something's wrong in the way I wrote it that should be corrected before I keep using this code, because it's exactly the same as before, and results should not change in a good code.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int MakeSample();
int PrintSample();

int *sample;

int main(void)
{
    MakeSample();
    PrintSample();
}

int MakeSample()
{
    int sampleSize;
    int valueN;

    printf("Enter size of your sample: ");

    scanf("%d", &sampleSize);

    sample = malloc(sampleSize * sizeof(int));

    for (int i = 1; i <= sampleSize; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter value #%d: ", i);

        scanf("%d", &valueN);

        sample[i - 1] = valueN;
    }
}

int PrintSample()
{
    for (int k = 1; k <= sizeof(sample); k++)
    {
        printf("Value #%d: %d\n", k, sample[k - 1]);
    }
}
```

The result is this for a sampleSize of 1:

```
Value #1: 1
Value #2: 0
Value #3: 0
Value #4: 0
Value #5: 0
Value #6: 0
Value #7: 133057
Value #8: 0
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I'm afraid this question does not match what this site is about. Code Review is about improving existing, working code. Code Review is not the site to ask for help in fixing or changing *what* your code does. Once the code does what you want, we would love to help you do the same thing in a cleaner way! Please see our [help center](/help/on-topic) for more information.

Comment: Sorry about the misunderstanding, I won't do it again.